# Knockout checked and click both (prevent double checkbox switch)

Tags: knockout.js

I have the checkbox described like this:

```
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" data-bind="
    click: function () { handle_compare($element) },
    checked: is_product_compared">
```

.handle_compare() just inverts the observable "is_product_compared", the problem is to allow a normal behavior to this checkbox, if I click on it, seems it double switches, and I never see the changes.

If I bind handle_compare to button - all is ok, checkbox switches normally. Is there a way to allow both this bindings?

You can see a demo here, button is ok, but the checkbox has wrong behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/g5rpcw2c/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need your inline click handler to return true:

http://jsfiddle.net/g5rpcw2c/2/

either:

```
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" data-bind="
    click: function () { handle_compare($element); return true; },
    checked: is_product_compared">
```

or (since handle_compare already returns true):

```
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" data-bind="
    click: function () { return handle_compare($element) },
    checked: is_product_compared">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I read about returning "true", but it was placed wrong.. I hope this answer helps to others.

Comment: Thank you. Returning `true` solved a simmial issue for me