# Checked always evaluates to false

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```js
function AppViewModel() {  
    var thisModel = this;
  
    thisModel.handleOnClick = function() {
       console.log('checked: ', thisModel.settings.checked());
       
       //console.log('new value: ', newValue);
      if(thisModel.settings.checked() === "checked"){
        thisModel.settings.checked(null);
      }else{
        thisModel.settings.checked("checked");
      }
    };

     thisModel.settings = {
        checked: ko.observable("checked"),
        onClick: thisModel.handleOnClick
    };
  
    return thisModel;
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: settings.checked, click: settings.onClick">
```

The toggle function, `handleOnClick` is broken.  The checkbox remains checked no matter what.  What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using a `click` binding with a checkbox, your handler [must return `true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29393750/1287183) so that you don't prevent the default action (to toggle the checkbox).

But in general, there should be no need to use the `click` binding on a checkbox. Just use `checked`.

```js
function AppViewModel() {  
    var thisModel = this;
  
     thisModel.settings = {
        checked: ko.observable(true),
     };

     thisModel.settings.checked.subscribe(function (value) {
         console.log("checked: " + value);
     });
  
     return thisModel;
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: settings.checked">
```